# How to read certain chunks of a text file. Java

Tags: java, file, file-io

So I have a text file (file.txt) that has a long number in it. Basically, the number is like that of PI. I need to read that number 10 digits at a time from the file. For example:

Number in the file:

```
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628
```

I need to take the first ten digits of it: `3.141592653` and pass it into a function that 
returns `true` or `false`. If I receive a `true`, then the function stops and returns those 10 
digits. If the number is false, then I take the next 10 digits, `1415926535`, and pass it 
into the function.

How would I go about reading the file the 10 digits at a time.

Comment: Please share your attempts so far, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to only pull the 10 digit segments. I can open the file and read the whole thing. However, I am having trouble limiting it to 10 digits.

Comment: So what you're saying is you can get the file, you can read it but you have trouble figuring out how to get the first 10 digits. A substring as it were. A substring from the first index to the 10th, and then the next 10. As a loop as it were. A loop until the end of the string. A substring in a loop.

Comment: Load in the entire string into a `String` variable, and use the `subString(int, int)` method to split the original string into smaller pieces. This assumes that the string isn't millions and millions of characters long, but then your approach (brute-force) would be wrong.

Comment: Am i the only one that gets the point that he wants to read a specific amount of chars from a specific offset in a file because hes probably sitting on a 50TB file.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, i think its most of what you need (sorry the bad formatting im realy in a hury)

Answer (score 0):

you can get this line to String variable and substring it using '.' 
Then get only the decimal part and chunk them in the size of 10 and store it into an array.

If you post your code we can help more than this.

To chunk you can use [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here is a draft, build this logic into your existing code, edit your question and we can help you to finalize it.

Key Methods to use are FileReaders read() Method to get a single char (or -1 if there are no more) and skip() to ignore a certain amount of chars (already processed)

(Sorry the bad formating im a bit in a hurry)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class SimpleReader {

    File theSourceFile = new File("D:\\<yourPath>\\input.txt");
    int nrOfCharsToRead = 10;
    int nrOfCharsProcessed = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new SimpleReader().process();       
    }

    public void process(){

        System.out.println(getNext(nrOfCharsToRead));
        System.out.println(getNext(nrOfCharsToRead));
        System.out.println(getNext(nrOfCharsToRead));
        System.out.println(getNext(nrOfCharsToRead));
        System.out.println(getNext(nrOfCharsToRead));
        System.out.println(getNext(nrOfCharsToRead));
        System.out.println(getNext(nrOfCharsToRead));
        System.out.println(getNext(nrOfCharsToRead));
        System.out.println(getNext(nrOfCharsToRead));
        System.out.println(getNext(nrOfCharsToRead));

    }

    private String getNext(int nrOfCharsToRead){

        try {

               FileReader reader = new FileReader(theSourceFile);
               StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();

               reader.skip(nrOfCharsProcessed);

               char c;
               int counter = 0;
               StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

               while((c = (char) reader.read()) != -1 && counter < nrOfCharsToRead){
                   sb.append(c);
                   nrOfCharsProcessed++;
                   counter++;
               }

               reader.close();

               return sb.toString();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } 

        return "";

    }

}
```

Comment: If were not talking about a realy realy large file and you have enoth memory to read the whole file the other answers are easier to implement ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did Something like this , hope its useful, I hardcoded the value assuming you get the value from text file

```
package javaapplication14;


public class JavaApplication14 {

    static int strt = 0;
    static int end = 10;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String num = "3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628";


        boolean val = false;

        while (val == false) {
            val = check(num.substring(strt, end));
            strt = end;
            end = end + 10;
        }
    }

    private static boolean check(String substring) {
        String num = substring;
        //just for checking (the first ten digits of the string)
        String chk = "3.14159265";
        System.out.println("substr " + substring);
        if (chk.equals(num)) {
            System.out.println("equal");
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some generic code which should get you started:

```
String text;
int index = 0;

String subText = text.substring(index, index+10);
while (method(subText) && ((index + 10) < text.length())) {
    subText = text.substring(index, index + 10);
    index += 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache Commons IO:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

...
String fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("pi.txt"));
String tenCharacters = Arrays.toString(fileContent.split("(?<=\\G..........)"));
doStuff(tenCharacters);
...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String text;
text = "3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628";
int index = 0; 
while (index<text.length()) {
    String string = text.substring(index, Math.min(index+10,text.length()));

    //function to process 10 digits. if true break
    if(processDigits(string))
         break;

    index+=10;
}
```

Comment: He wanted to load the data from a text file - not hardcode the value into his program.

Comment: @Izmaki: he knows how to load it.